# Get Verified keystore to sign apk locally

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore, keytool

I'm a newbie to android development. I created my developer account. I'd like to get a `.jks` file which I created using `keytool` . I've been trying to read guides by google but I'm confused. When I create and sign an existing APK and try to install on my phone, it gives me an error of installation blocked. Play doesn't recognise this developer. How do I get a `.jks` or any other credential that I can sign locally with and NOT get the error while installing?

Do help guys. Thanks.

I Tried to:

1. Create a keystore (`upload.jks`) using `keytool`.
2. Zipaligned and Signed an existing apk using `apksigner`.
3. Tried installing the apk on my phone.
4. Got the error of play protect. I don't want the error popping
   up.

In this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing), it's been said,

> If you manage your own app signing key and keystore, when you sign your
> APK, you will sign it locally using your app signing key and upload
> the signed APK directly to the Google Play Store for distribution.

I'd like to manage my keys and sign myself locally. What's the procedure to do that?

Comment: Have you allowed "Allow unknown sources" in the security settings of your device?

Comment: You you want to disable the error, disable play protection scanning for apps installed via adb (see developer options).

Comment: @Pierre yes I have. I can install. I just get this popup showing me warning. @Robert I want to sign the apk so that this `warning` doesn't pop up when I try to install.

Comment: There is no way to sign the APK in a way Google does not warn. This feature is designed to warn for apps by "unrecognised developers" (thus apps that come from developers that don't have an app in Play Store) and you are an unrecognized developer from Google's perspective.

Comment: @Robert can you please tell me, How do I become a recognised dev? Thanks.

Comment: Google does not publish (or I simply don't know them) what they their definition of a "known developer" is but most likely it includes being registered at Google and publishing an app there that is getting positive critics (my guess).

Comment: Today you don't upload APK files to Google but AppBundles and those app bundles are signed with an upload key only. The final APK signing is performed by Google in the Google cloud and the signing key can be uploaded to Google or generated by Google in the cloud. As far as I know uploading of signed APK files is only available for legacy Android apps (apps that exists in Play Store before certain date).